# Gitlab autostart on boot

Tags: gitlab

first of all I'm sorry for my english.

I've recently installed GitLab on a Debian 7.1 server, and don't start on boot. I've checked /etc/init.d, but there is no script for Gitlab.

How I can add Gitlab to startup?

I've used the Omnibus deb installer from download page, and if I run "gitlab-ctl start" works perfect.

Greetings and thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On CentOS 7,
There is a symbolic link,

/etc/systemd/system/default.target.wants/gitlab-runsvdir.service -> /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/runit/files/default/gitlab-runsvdir.service

And the content of gitlab-runsvdir.service is as like this

```
[Unit] Description=GitLab Runit supervision process

[Service] ExecStart=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start
Restart=always
```

I hope there is a similar in Debian 7.

Comment: Thanks!!! Finally seems to be starting, but maybe take a long time and I thought that isn't starting (or maybe i've changed anything).

Answer (score 7):

```
systemctl enable gitlab-runsvdir
```

If your system is using systemd (RHEL/CentOS 7) instead of init; This is easier :)

```
 [meebo@server ~]# sudo systemctl enable gitlab-runsvdir
 Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/gitlab-
 runsvdir.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/gitlab-runsvdir.service.
```

Answer (score 4):

This did not work for me, *and* was rather annoying to find the answer:

What worked was:

On Centos 6.7:
Edit the upstart file /etc/init/gitlab-runsvdir.conf and comment out the line:

> start on runlevel [2345]